# building custom simple shopping cart using wordpress plugin

Tags: plugins

i want to build custom wordpress base shopping cart using plugin, i'm new to building plugin, i can build theme easily.

i have custom table which i can use as custom post types too that will act as products.

now i want to create a plugin that add link "add to cart" to post detail page that when clicked add entry to cart table ( custom table ) this is the only way right ?

i have searched but could't find help anywhere how i can add link the way i want, can someone guide me to a tutorial or article how to do it.

i don't need checkout functionality just add to cart and email to admin.

i need help not down vote.

Comment: What is "the way you want" exactly? Please list what had you looked at, so that people don't have to repeat your search and suggest same things.

Comment: Thanks @Rarst "the way i want" means using plugin, if i install my plugin there should be link add to cart on product detail page ( or single post page ) and if deactivated it disappears, and how that link will call plugin function that will add post id to cart table.

Comment: i think filter hooks will do that task, reading action and hooks...